# web whatsapp send text and imagen

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, whatsapp

I'm try to send a message with whatsapp web url, right now i can send the message but just the text, this is my code and works.

```
<a href="https://web.whatsapp.com/send?text= !!! This is my code  0H78RT !!! %0A https://mypublicUrl.com.co/documents?gad=1"  
 rel="nofollow noopener" 
 target="_blank" 
 className="share-icon">
 Share via Whatsapp
</a>
```

web reuslt
[image]

But i need add a imagen like this, I have been try to use &image="https://panda.png" at the end od the url, but this doesn't works. this is the final result I need to deployd.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to send images (and other media), you would need an account with one of the [WhatsApp Business Solution Providers](https://get.chat/blog/whatsapp-business-solution-providers/).

The best of them is [360dialog](https://www.360dialog.com/).

To build media messages, interactive messages and even more, I recommend you registering for [get.chat Inbox](https://docs.360dialog.com/integrations/guides/get.chat).

I am a co-founder and CTO so I am open to answer any questions if you want to know more about our solution. [Here](https://docs.get.chat/wa-integration-api/) is also a link to the API docs if you're interested in learning more by yourself.